# Odd issue with Excel pie charts

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am having a weird issue that I was hoping was a quick fix with Excel 2013 for a pie chart. However, I can't figure out what's wrong! I am attempting to make a pie chart out of a column that looks something like this (not an exhaustive list):

```
Reason for Discharge
Successful completion of treatment/Graduated
Successful completion of treatment/Graduated
Successful completion of treatment/Graduated
Client withdrew - unable to locate
No longer eligible for program
Other
Successful completion of treatment/Graduated
No longer eligible for program
Successful completion of treatment/Graduated
```

When I click on Insert, then Recommended Charts, I get the message that there are no recommended charts.

Then when I click on All Charts, then Pie, all of the rows become part of the Chart Title (not just "Reason for Discharge") and no chart appears! Why is not making a pie chart?

Comment: I may have found a workaround by creating a pivot chart to summarize the data (count of each type). From there, I was able to make a pie chart easily. I don't remember having to do this with previous versions of Excel...

Comment: Congrats on solving your problem.  Why not add it as an answer and mark it as accepted to help others who have the same issue?

Answer (score 2):

Even with previous versions of Excel, pie charts, as horrible as they may be, only work with numbers. If you only have a range of text values you will need to do some form of aggregation, so you end up with a table that has text and numbers. The numbers will be used for the size of the pie slices. The text will most likely be the slice label.

This has not changed in Excel 2013.

Please keep in mind that a pie chart is hardly ever the best way to visualise data. Use pies when you have two or three data points only. With more data points, pie charts are not reader-friendly. A horizontal bar chart sorted by size is much easier to read.

For more information please refer to [Save the Pies for Dessert](https://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/visual_business_intelligence/save_the_pies_for_dessert.pdf) by Stephen Few.

Comment: Thank you for your response and the link! You're right-- the pie charts are overwhelming but I'm being asked to present that way even though I'd lean towards a bar graph.  However, even when I change chart types to a bar graph, the same issue is happening and I don't remember having had that issue before. Shouldn't I be able to present in a bar graph without having to aggregate?

Comment: No, Charts have never done any aggregation. You always need to feed numbers to a chart.